# Use like something in a sentence

Tags: sentence

> I do know I can just click on that
>   person's profile once every week/day,
>   but I think automated **"inbox" like**
>   feature would be better

I'm talking about Inbox feature provided by the stackexchange sites, is that correct? I felt that I should add quotes, because I'm not referring to inbox, but something that is named inbox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I would use:

> I do know I can just click on that person's profile once every week or day, but I think an automated inbox-like feature would be better.

Changes:

- Avoid the slash
- Use the indefinite article 'an'
- Use the hyphen instead of quotes

Comment: I understand, but why "Avoid the slash" ? I think a slash is something "very" english.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the first two mistakes by editing his answer and only mention the one as an answer, because that's really what his question is?

Comment: Because I'm an old fuddy-duddy?  Probably.  The slash is meant to mean 'or', and the word looks better.  The English style books that I learned from discouraged the slash - so I'm reiterating what I learned a long time ago.  In engineering circles, 'week/day' would be 'weeks per day', and the answer had better be 1/7 (unless you're working in business weeks, in which case, I suppose it is 1/5).

Comment: @Borror0: if I had edit privileges, perhaps.  I don't have them (yet).  I suspect that the OP is speaking English as a second language; I hope that my explanations will help him or her improve their 'Use of English' - as well as provide an answer to the direct or main question.

Comment: +1 for those edit privileges and for being an "old fuddy-duddy" (wait... that didn't come out right when I write it) ;)

Comment: It should be noted that the hyphen doesn't replace the quotes, it's needed *with* the quotes too.  At least in the style guide in my brain (never read one, yet).